# Using VBA to get MDX Data

Tags: excel, vba, mdx

I'm having a hard time getting results back in Excel connecting to an MDX database. Below is my code (I am incredibly new at this, so please be patient.) I did hijack someone's error code, so that part is not mine. The query runs through but I receive no data in Excel. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()       
    Sheets("DataDump").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Department"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "provider=MSOLAP.3;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=XXXXX;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset    

    strSQL = "select [product].[base color] on columns "
    strSQL = strSQL & " From XXX "
    strSQL = strSQL & " Where [Date].[Fiscal Week].&[2016]&[10] "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    Sheets("DataDump").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Set Lists = Nothing
    strSQL = vbNullString
    StartDate = 0
    EndDate = 0
    SeasonYear = vbNullString
    PriorYear = vbNullString
    TXTYear = 0

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With    
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Sheets("DataDump").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    Set Lists = Nothing
    strSQL = vbNullString
    StartDate = 0
    EndDate = 0
    SeasonYear = vbNullString
    PriorYear = vbNullString
    TXTYear = 0

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With

    'Error Message
    MsgBox "An Error occurred while retrieving data: " & Err.Description   
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to use the Multi-Dimensional ADO reference. See this: https://support.sas.com/documentation/tools/oledb/cs_adomdcellset.htm

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of going straight to a cube via vba.

I've used this additional object `ADOMD.Cellset` to capture the results of the `mdx`.

```
Sub getFromCube()

Dim strConn As String
strConn = _
    "Provider=MSOLAP.6;" & _
    "Data Source=imxxxxxx;" & _                                     '<<<name of your server here
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE;" & _  '<<<name of your Adv Wrks db here
    "Integrated Security=SSPI"

Dim pubConn As ADODB.Connection
Set pubConn = New ADODB.Connection
pubConn.CommandTimeout = 0
pubConn.Open strConn

Dim cs As ADOMD.Cellset
Set cs = New ADOMD.Cellset

Dim myMdx As String
myMdx = _
  " SELECT" & _
  "  NON EMPTY" & _
  "    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[AB]&[CA] ON 0," & _
  "  NON EMPTY" & _
  "    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 1" & _
  " FROM [Adventure Works];"

With cs
    .Open myMdx, pubConn
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = cs(0, 0)
    .Close
End With


End Sub
```